# Apache Spark Streaming Error : Attempt to use BlockRDD after its block have been removes

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to run an apache streaming program which recieves a stream of data,do some processing,save it on cache,and compare the data with the next stream. My program executes for the very first batch it exits by the below error on next stream.

```
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException:
 execute, tree: TungstenExchange hashpartitioning(at
 org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$.attachTree(package.scala:49)
         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Exchange.doExecute(Exchange.scala:247)
 Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage
 failure: Task creation failed: org.apache.spark.SparkException:
 Attempted to use BlockRDD[1] at socketTextStream at
 StreamExample.java:56 after its blocks have been removed!
 org.apache.spark.rdd.BlockRDD.assertValid(BlockRDD.scala:83)
 org.apache.spark.rdd.BlockRDD.getPreferredLocations(BlockRDD.scala:56)
 org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$preferredLocations$2.apply(RDD.scala:257)
 org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$preferredLocations$2.apply(RDD.scala:257)
 scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
 org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.preferredLocations(RDD.scala:256)
 org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$getPreferredLocsInternal(DAGScheduler.scala:1545)
 org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$getPreferredLocsInternal$2$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcVI$sp(DAGScheduler.scala:1556)
```

I am trying to join stream data to an existing cached data and perform some operation using join statements and cache it again.

```
static DataFrame active=null;    
foreachRDD
    {

        DataFrame x=sqlContext.read().json(rdd);
       if(active==null)
    {
    active=x;
    }
    else
    {
    Dataframe f=active.join(x)
    other functions using join statements
    active.persist()
    }
```

Comment: Please can you post a code snippet? It's not clear whether you are comparing two streams, or comparing the data at different batches of the same stream.  (if the latter are you using `streamingContext.remember(someTime)` so that the data is persisted across batches, or using a windowing operation?)

Comment: What do you actually want to do? It looks like you're doing joins across RDDs in a DStream which in turn looks like a stateful/window operation.

Comment: Yes. I it's a window operation.  I could achieve this by window . I was looking to have a continous online application rather than time specified.